# Overload Methods autocasting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting

Hi there I was wondering if there is any other way to do this casts automatically

```
if (currentWeapon is MeleeWeapon)
        Fire(currentWeapon as MeleeWeapon);
    else if (currentWeapon is GunWeapon)
        Fire(currentWeapon as GunWeapon);
    else if (currentWeapon is MachineGun)
        Fire(currentWeapon as MachineGun);
```

All the methods called are overloaded like this:

```
void Fire(MeleeWeapon weapon)
void Fire(GunWeapon weapon)
void Fire(MachineGun weapon)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably rather want an abstract base class `Weapon` that has a virtual method `Fire()`.

Then you can have an instance of a derived class and use it like this (example):

```
 Weapon currentWeapon = new MeeleWeapon();
 currentWeapon.Fire();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it other way round ... rather all your `Fire()` method probably should take a base representation like below and then in your particular method you can cast it accordingly

```
void Fire(BaseWeapon weapon)
```

Moreover, when you already know ahead about the type then instead of doing a `if` condition you can probably just say

```
    Fire((MeleeWeapon)currentWeapon);
```